# Bad arguments for libopus create encoder

Tags: c, java-native-interface

currently I'm trying to build JNI-bindings for libopus. My current problem ist that I have a C-method like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL 
Java_de_akuz_android_libopus_OpusCodecFactory_encodercreate(JNIEnv * env, jint samplingRate, jint channels, jint application)
{
jclass resultClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"de/akuz/android/libopus/OpusFactoryResult");
jobject result = (*env)->AllocObject(env,resultClass);

jfieldID pointerFieldID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, resultClass,"pointer","J");
jfieldID errorFieldID = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, resultClass,"errorCode","I");


int error;
OpusEncoder* encoder = opus_encoder_create(samplingRate, channels, application, &error);

char buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "Pointer address: %p", encoder); // puts string into buffer
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "OpusNative", buf);


(*env)->SetLongField(env, result, pointerFieldID, encoder);
(*env)->SetIntField(env, result, errorFieldID, error);
return result;
}
```

When I call this method from JNI with the values 48000 for sample rate, 2 for channels and 2049 as id for application (taken from opus defines) a always get the error code -1 and null pointer back. I already tried casting the sample rate to an opus_int32 but it didn't change anything. Also I tried to pass the defined OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO directly instead if its integer value but it also didn't change anything. Unfortunately I'm more of a Java guy so I would appreciate any held on this problem(s) in my C code.

Comment: I took a look in the file `opus_defines.h`. There you can find `#define OPUS_BAD_ARG -1`. Seems you have still a problem with the parameter you give inside the call `opus_encoder_create`.

Comment: You can try to write a pure simple C program without the fancy jni things around and try to reproduce the error. if so, then there is a problem with the library itself. You should also try to use only 1 channel and/or a smaller sampling rate.

Comment: `opus_int32` and `jint` are equivalent to `int`. So there is nothing to cast here. If you really use the parameters like described in your question I cannot see any reason why the call should fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry, but obviously I'm blind (or stupid). My method declaration is all wrong

```
Java_de_akuz_android_libopus_OpusCodecFactory_encodercreate(JNIEnv * env, jint samplingRate, jint channels, jint application)
```

I have the parameter for the JNI environment but not the parameter for the calling object. It seems that C isn't interested in the amount of arguments of the native method in the Java code or the type of the arguments. Because of the missing jobject after JNIEnv all my parameters were shifted by one with samplingRate having the value of the pointer for the missing jobject.
The correct method declaration would be

```
Java_de_akuz_android_libopus_OpusCodecFactory_encodercreate(JNIEnv * env, jobject object, jint samplingRate, jint channels, jint application)
```

I hope that anyone running into the same problem will find my answer useful.

Comment: Yes you are right. C doesnt care about how many parameters or not you push on the stack. By the way I also did not see the wrong function signature. Maybe next time better also to logging the parameters you expect to use for the call.